# Double data by retrieving data and ordening by ascending

Tags: ios, parse-platform, tableview

I am retrieving data from parse.com
I want to set them in ascending order, but I see that some data are about 10x times double, while I just want to show each cell to one username data.

Can you see what I do wrong?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
if (currentUser) {
    NSLog(@"Current user: %@", currentUser.username);
}

else {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLogin" sender:self];
}


}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Aanvragen"];
[query whereKey:@"RecipientIDs" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser]objectId]];
[query orderByDescending:@"Datum"];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }

    else {
        // we found messages
        self.messages = objects;
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        NSLog(@"Retrieved %d messages", [self.messages count]);
    }
}];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [self.messages count];
}

#pragma mark - Table view
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


PFObject *message = [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [message objectForKey:@"senderName"];

NSString *fileType = [message objectForKey:@"FileType"];

self.objectId = [message objectId];
NSLog(@" objectId: %@", [self objectId]);

if ([fileType isEqualToString:@"image"]) {
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_image"];
}

else if ([fileType isEqualToString:@"video"]) {
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_video"];
}

else {
    cell.imageView.image = nil;
}
return cell;
}
```

Comment: What does "some data are about 10x times double" mean? That you are receiving duplicate entries? And what kind of column is "RecipientIDs"?

Comment: hi, yeah i mean that i ream receiving 20 times the same entry. 
RecipientIDs is the objectID of the recipients of the message. Thats each message >1 recipientID for each user. 

Do I make mistakes in the tableviewcell ?

Comment: I understand what the RecipientIDs column contains. But what kind of column is it? Array of strings maybe? Or is it just a string representing the objectId of a user?

Comment: recipientID is just a string representing the objectID of the receivende user.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your data model. Instead of using RecipientIDs and storing objectId strings in that, create a new column called "recipient" which is a pointer to the User class, and then put the user object in it. This is the correct way of creating relations between classes:

```
aanvragen[@"recipient"] = [PFUser currentUser];
```

Now you could change your query constraint like so:

```
[query whereKey:@"recipient" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
```

and you should get only 1 of each object.